# Prove sequence of continuous functions is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cauchy-sequences, supremum-and-infimum

I have a sequence of continuous functions that, $f_{J}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, J=1,2,3, \ldots$ converges to a function $f$. $f_{J}$ is continuous function and is piecewise linear on each interval in $\mathcal{P}^{J}$ (i.e. the powerset) and therefore completely defined by its values in $X^{J}$. First of all, it is defined that $f_{J+1}(t)=f_{J}(t)$ $\forall$ $t \in X^{J}$, where set $X^{J}=\{t_{0},t_{1},\ldots,t_{N}\}=\{0,2^{-J},2\times 2^{-J},3\times 2^{-J} \ldots,1\}$. For $ t=\left(2k-1 \right) 2^{-\left(J+1\right)} \in X^{J+1}\setminus X^{J}, k=1,\ldots,2^{J}.$ It is also defined that, $$f_{J+1}(t)=f_{J}(t)+\left( -1\right)^{k+J+1}2^{-J/(2-1)}$$
This definition of $f_{J+1}$ is extended to the whole of [0,1].

I need to prove that the sequence $f_{1},f_{2},\ldots$ converges uniformly to a continuous function, $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, by showing that is it is a Cauchy sequence in the sup-norm.

$\textbf{My approach:}$
If $X$ is a complete metric space, then every Cauchy sequence $\{x_{n}\} \subset X$ converges to a limit $x$ since the function provided is complete with respect to the metric induced by the sup-norm. So, all I want to do is show that this is a Cauchy and by completeness it has to converge. I am not sure how can I go about proving it is a Cauchy, and that is what I need help with.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site.. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Your sequence of functions are defined on a compact space. Moreover you know they converge to f. So pick any 2 arbitrarily  $f_j, f_k $ and then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @ Philip, so are you suggesting some kind of induction based proof?

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your def'n of $f_{J+1}(t)$ .The  term $2^{-J/(2-1)}$ doesn't look right.Please edit. If your def'n is what I think it is (when edited) then $\sup |f_{J+1}(x)-f_J(x)|$ is about $2^{-J}$ which implies it is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence {$f_n$} is said to be Cauchy if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is an integer $N$ such that for $n,m \in \Bbb N$ then $|f_n - f_m| < \epsilon$ when $n>m>N$

So we know that $f_J \to f$

Then by the triangle inequality $|f_n - f_m| \le |f_n - f| + |f_m - f|$

Since we know $f_J$ converges to $f$, then by definition $|f_J - f| < \frac{\epsilon }{2}$ where $\frac{\epsilon }{2}$ is arbitrary

Finally, $|f_n - f_m| \le |f_n - f| + |f_m - f| < \frac{\epsilon }{2} + \frac{\epsilon }{2} \to |f_n - f_m| < \epsilon$

This shows that {$f_n$} is Cauchy.

You need to show that for your specific function, $|f_J - f| < \frac{\epsilon }{2}$ can be interpreted to be bounded above by this arbitrary $\frac{\epsilon }{2}$ which will show that it too converges.